# To read esoteric writings or simple journal article gain more for me?

Tags: reading

I can understand 80% article in bbc news or yahoo.
To read esoteric writings  or simple journal article gain more for me?

Comment: I don't know which would help you gain more, but I think reading both might help you gain most.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read more advanced journalism. However it is also important to pay attention to grammar and syntax. Your vocabulary seems fine, however I would suggest you turn your attention to the laws that govern the English language; it will help you better grasp the mechanics.